# ASIHTTP save data on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I have an app that uses ASIHTTP to interact with the server.
I have a requirement to store some of the data if not all (still to decide) on the iPhone in a sort of caching mechanism. In this way I can access the data even offline: so I need a syncronization mechanism too.
Is there a feature within this library to save permanently the response received from the server?
The response is a JSON so it's not a problem if I need to do some mapping before  store the data.
If not, are there some library that help to do it?

Comment: you can store the JSON file on your app as it, or you can replicate your remote db in your app using Core Data, take a look to this article for an idea about the synchronization mechanism http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found both (@taffarel & @Manjit Bhuriya) your answers correct.
But I was looking for a solution that comes within the ASIHTTP library.
I digged more on the code I working on and I found there was a cache but never used because there were too many checks on the network.
I relaxed that checks and now the cache works.
For now I decided to stay with this.

Thanks too both, very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

To store data into your device you can use following techniques.
[Property Lists](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i)

[Archiving and Serialization mechanism](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i)
 SQLite framework for ios or 
[Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

Comment: @Fili mark this question as answered if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Store data through Sqlite manager, arrays, userdefaults or Core data, moreover you can create text file and save your JSON response in that file and set file location in the document directory.